# CakePHP associations: handle null id

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, associations

I have this model:

```
Proforma
  ->hasMany('ItemProformas', ['foreignKey' => 'proforma_id']);
  ->belongsTo('Customers', ['foreignKey' => 'customer_id']);
  ->belongsTo('ProformaStates', ['foreignKey' => 'proforma_state_id']);
  ->hasMany('Invoices', ['foreignKey' => 'proforma_id']);

ItemProformas
  ->belongsTo('Proformas', ['foreignKey' => 'proforma_id', 'joinType' => 'INNER']);
  ->belongsTo('ItemDeliveryNotes', ['foreignKey' => 'item_delivery_note_id']);

ItemDeliveryNotes
    ->belongsTo('DeliveryNotes', ['foreignKey' => 'delivery_note_id', 'joinType' => 'INNER']);
    ->belongsTo('ItemOrders', ['foreignKey' => 'item_order_id']);
    ->belongsTo('ItemOrdersTypes', ['foreignKey' => 'item_orders_type_id']);
    ->belongsTo('Products', ['foreignKey' => 'product_id']);
```

Each `ItemProforma` *may* have one `ItemDeliveryNotes`, otherwise the foreign key will be `null`. Here my `paginate` call:

```
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => [
        'Customers',
        'ProformaStates',
        'ItemProformas' => ['ItemDeliveryNotes' => ['DeliveryNotes']]
    ]
];
```

With this model, I get all the `itemProforma` that *have* `item_delivery_note_id` set. Instead I'm interesed to get them all, even if `item_delivery_note_id` is `null`.

I'm not sure if `belongsTo` is correct here (I mean in `ItemProformas` definition). But `hasOne` implies it *has* one associated row, not *may* have one.

What is the correct syntax to retrieve *all* `itemProformas` even if they don't have any `ItemDeliveryNote` associated? But if they have, I need to retrieve the `ItemDeliveryNote` object as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The association type depends on your schema. If the foreign key is in the source table, then it's `belongsTo`, if the foreign key is in the target table, then it's `hasOne`.

Whether a related record must exist primarily depends on the schema too, not on the type of association. If the foreign key is nullable, then the related record is optional. If and how you implement enforcing that constraint on application level is a different story.

That being said, `ItemDeliveryNotes` and `DeliveryNotes` are both `belongsTo` that will use joins by default, so both associations will be joined into the same query, and since you've configured the `DeliveryNotes` association to use an `INNER` join, it will exclude rows where no `DeliveryNotes` exist, which of course is also the case when no `ItemDeliveryNotes` exist.

Assuming your schema is modeled correctly/properly, you could for example change your association config to use a `LEFT` join by default in case applicable, or you could change the configuration for the containment on a per query basis (being it manually, or by using a custom finder):

```php
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => [
        'Customers',
        'ProformaStates',
        'ItemProformas' => [
            'ItemDeliveryNotes' => [
                'DeliveryNotes' => [
                    'joinType' => \Cake\Database\Query::JOIN_TYPE_LEFT,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Changing the fetching strategy for `ItemDeliveryNotes` could work too (though it might be quite taxing depending on the amount of records), ie using the `select` strategy instead of the `join` strategy, then the associated `ItemDeliveryNotes` records are being retrieved in a separate query, and thus won't affect retrieval of `ItemProformas`:

```php
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => [
        'Customers',
        'ProformaStates',
        'ItemProformas' => [
            'ItemDeliveryNotes' => [
                'strategy' => \Cake\ORM\Association::STRATEGY_SELECT,
                'DeliveryNotes',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the join type to LEFT in the model, because it was wrong.